# OpenCV findContours() detects contours only if the image is saved and read beforehand

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, contour

Providing some context:
I am trying to get the number of boxes in this image,
[image]

I have the above image stored in an ndarray blank_img.

If I run the following:

```
v = np.median(blank_img)
sigma = 0.33
lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
edges = cv2.Canny(blank_img, lower, upper, 3)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges, np.ones((2, 2), dtype=np.uint8))

cnts= cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
```

len(cnts) is equal to 1.
But if i save the array blank_img before the canny edge detection and the findContours, as follows:

```
cv2.imwrite('boxes.jpg', blank_img)

blank_img = cv2.imread('boxes.jpg')
```

Now when i run my findContour code snippet, len(cnts) is > 1. I would like to know how to fix it so that I don't need to have an image saving overhead.

~~EDIT~~
Find the following code which I used to create blank_img

```
blank_img = 255*np.zeros((height, width, 3), np.uint8)
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line
    cv2.line(blank_img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(255,255,255),1)
```

Where `lines` is a list of lines returned by HoughLinesP:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi / 180, 100, None,minlinelength,maxlinegap)
```

Comment: Please check the shape of blank_img and edges image before finding contours in both approaches and see if there is any difference.

Comment: I have checked the shapes of both arrays in both approaches and they seem to be the same. @RahulKedia

Comment: Hard to say, since you didn't provide a proper [mcve] -- the issue is likely in the code that creates `blank_img`, which you didn't show for some reason. | Also, if the image really is blank, as the variable name would suggest, I'm not sure what you expect to find in it...

Comment: I named it  ` blank_img ` because I made a blank array with 0's, so I could use cv2.lines to draw the above-shown lines on it, also check my edit to find how blank_img is created. @DanMašek

Comment: RETR_TREE gives me all the possible hierarchies, but I only want the outermost contours, is there a way to get that from RETR_TREE?

Comment: Yes, use the Hierarchy data of RETR_TREE for that. [Refer to this link for info about hierarchy.](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here lies the problem:

See this image:

[image: problem is here]

The small green independent rectangle at the bottom left corner is created when you save the image and read it again. The actual length of `cnts` should be 1(the outer big rectangle) only.

This small rectangle is appearing in the Canny edge image after you store the image and again read it. I don't know the reason why this is being detected when you store the image and then read it. Just remove the 2 lines and use the image directly only.

Comment: @Rohit Also, have a look at the edge images yourself in the two cases. Some weird thing is happening and the reason to that is unknown to me.

Comment: Yeah I witnessed it myself, there are multiple small boxes being detected in the bottom left, and I can't quite wrap my head around what is happening before/after just saving the image.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the pixel's color values in that region also, there is no change in them before and after saving the image.

Comment: @Rohit, Also I have checked the value of `v`, `lower` and, `upper`, they are all 0 in both the cases. Check them also on your end if they are not right. On passing 0 and 40 in place of lower and upper in Canny, the small box was removed, however, the problem inside the big box persists.

Comment: "I don't know the reason" -- JPEG artifacts and no thresholding before the call to canny. JPEG is a poor choice of format for a synthetic image like this.

Comment: @DanMašek, I agree, but the image passed to Canny have the same shapes(both are 3 channeled) in both the cases.

Comment: The shape is not relevant. JPEG turns some pixels around those lines from pure black (0,0,0) to a very dark gray (1,1,1). The colour difference is so small they're not visible to a human. But since the Canny thresholds are centered on the median, which (the picture being mostly black) is 0, they do get picked up by Canny, and then further smeared by the morphological operation.